# Civisualize extension doesn't show up as available when uploaded to extension directory

Tags: civireport, civisualize

I downloaded the master zip file from this extension to my extension directory of civicrm.

https://github.com/TechToThePeople/civisualize

I unzipped it in the extension directory. flushed cache.
The extension does not show up in the list in 
civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1

I'm using CiviCrm 4.6.5
According to the latest changes in github project, the extension should be compatible.

Comment: I am on 4.7alpha and it works well when I download, please check whether the civisualize folder does not contain another folder in itself containing the code.

Answer (score 3):

You may also need to check the uploaded extension's file permissions and user settings.

Also, clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

The Civizualize extesion became visible in the extensions list only after installing another extension. 
I have no idea why that is. But it now works.

Comment: Do you mean you had no other extension in your extension directory?

Comment: No, there was another extension already present.

Comment: Probably because you cleared cache :)

Answer (score 0):

It shows up for me after pressing "Refresh" on the Extensions page (I'm not sure if that is what you mean by "flushed cache"):

[image: Refresh]